# Three column layout doesn't work correctly in Google Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

Long ago I followed a tutorial to create a 3-column layout for my website; it used to work correctly in every browser, but now using Chrome it adds a margin on resulting in a blank space before any other element on the page.

This is a snippet of CSS and html code:

```css
*{margin:0; padding:0;}

body {
  font-family: "Gill Sans Mt", Arial, Helvetica;
  text-align:center; 
}

img { border: none }

body, html, #wrapper {
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  position:relative;
}

#wrapper {display: table;}

#left {
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  top:0;
  width:125px;
  height:100%;
  background-image:url(https://awranking.altervista.org/images/tile_sx1.jpg);
  background-repeat:repeat-y;
  z-index:-1;
  display: table-cell;
}

#right {
  position:absolute;
  right:0;
  top:0;
  width:125px;
  height:100%; 
  background-image:url(https://awranking.altervista.org/images/tile_dx1.jpg);
  background-repeat:repeat-y;
  z-index:-1;
  display: table-cell;
}

#middle {
  display: table-cell;
  height:100%;
  margin-bottom:30px;
  padding-bottom:30px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "https://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Test Page</title>
    <link href="test.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  </head>

  <body>

  <div id="wrapper">
    <div id="left"></div>

    <div id="middle"> 
    In girum imus nocte ecce et consumimur igni
    </div> 

    <div id="right"></div>
  </div> 

  </body>
</html>
```

And this is the test page I created, if you want to try it on your browsers:
[Test Page](https://awranking.altervista.org/test.php)

Comment: You should not use `position` property to set up a multi column layout in HTML, better use `display: inline-block;` property or CSS Grid or CSS Flexbox, it is a lot simpler and easier to maintain and understand. You can read about CSS Grid here : https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/.

Comment: Is there an explanation to the fact that it used to work correctly until a few months ago, and now it doesn't?

Comment: To be honnest, your layout is far from something which should be done so unfortunately I'm not gonna try to understand all the logic in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `position: absolute` should really not use to build your main layout, it should be used mainly to position things precisely in your page like modal or dialog box.

You should use `display: inline-block` or CSS Grid or CSS Flexbox.

With CSS Grid, if you want to set up a 3-column layout, you can just use `display: grid` on your parent container and `grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr` that create 3 columns instantly.

```css
#container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
}

#column-1 {
  background-color: red;
}
#column-2 {
  background-color: blue;
}
#column-3 {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="column-1">A</div>
  <div id="column-2">B</div>
  <div id="column-3">C</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I was wondering why I didn't use CSS grid when I created my (simple) website six years ago: I've just discovered that it's been introduced in late 2017, right?

Comment: @Hunter absolutely ! Before this, the layouts were made by `display: inline-block` property, floating blocks or flexbox mainly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code -- Using 3-column layout, with bootstrap Design Responsive

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <title>Hello, world!</title>
    <link href="test.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <style type="text/css">
        * {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }
        body {
            font-family: "Gill Sans Mt", Arial, Helvetica;
            text-align: center;
        }
        img {
            border: none
        }
        .left {
            width: 100%;
            background-image: url(https://awranking.altervista.org/images/tile_sx1.jpg);
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-size: cover;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 25px;
            color: #ffffff;

        }
        .right {
            width: 100%;
            background-image: url(https://awranking.altervista.org/images/tile_sx1.jpg);
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-size: cover;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 25px;
            color: #ffffff;

        }
        .middle {
            width: 100%;
            background-image: url(https://awranking.altervista.org/images/tile_sx1.jpg);
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-size: cover;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 25px;
            color: #ffffff;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
                <p class="left">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec tristique ligula eu tellus consectetur, vel imperdiet leo pharetra.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-12 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
                <p class="middle">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec tristique ligula eu tellus consectetur, vel imperdiet leo pharetra.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-12 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
                <p class="right">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec tristique ligula eu tellus consectetur, vel imperdiet leo pharetra.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```